# Make Html.TextBoxFor show non-initialized integer property as empty string in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper, html.textboxfor

I have added Html.TextBoxFor to my view:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.zip, String.Empty, new { @class = "gsTextBox", placeholder = "Enter your zip" });
```

And it shows 0 in the input instead of empty string.

I also have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887005/html-textboxfor-default-value-for-integer-decimal-to-be-empty-instead-of-0) solution, but it seems to be horrible. Or this is nice approach? Or maybe I should replace 0 by empty string using javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Try this* - Make int nullable

```
public int? zip { get;set; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, if you do not want to have to use nullables:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.zip, new { placeholder = "Enter your zip", @class = "gsTextBox", @Value = (Model.zip > 0 ? Model.zip.ToString() : string.Empty) })
```

The empty string will cause the placeholder to appear. In the event of a validation error or similar and returning to the page, this code will show the value the user entered... or the placeholder if not greater than 0.

Answer (score 0):

if you Wont change your Model by Nullable Property:

Use javascrip or Jquery Way.

```
$("input.no-init").val("");
```