# Set Html.EditorFor value empty instead of 0.00 in decimal field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My `Html.EditorFor` value is `0.00` instead of `empty` for decimal property as follows:

[image: Screenshot]

How can I set it to empty instead of 0.00?

Comment: Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19676387/1955268). Try to add DisplayFormat attribute to your model as suggested by Sel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `decimal` is `non-nullable` type and default value for `decimal` is `0.00` if you don't provide any explicit value. And in your case when you are initializing your model class you are not providing any value to it and that's why its taking default value 0.00.

You can remove the `0.00` from your form input field by simply as follows:

```
public class YourModelClass
{
    ..........
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:#.#}")]
    public decimal CurrentSoftMin { get; set; }
    ..........
}
```

Comment: what if the format string is `"{0:0.#}"`?

Comment: in my case, i had to change it to nullable: `public decimal? CurrentSoftMin ...`

Answer (score -1):

In your code change code to this
`[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:#.#}")]
decimal  InterestRate { get; set; }`

and in view

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.InterestRate)
```