# HTML Helper checking if the date is MinValue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, spark-view-engine

Can I configure the HTML Helper to display String.Empty if my date is MinValue?

```
${Html.TextBoxFor(v=>v.Date)}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I think you have the wrong approach. Instead, use a ViewModel to do this type of formatting/logic.

Comment: I agree with @vidalsasoon, the output of the helper is a bunch of html, so you can't control its output without changing the helper or building your own.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do it in your View?

Caution: Razor syntax

```
@if(v.Date != DateTime.MinValue)
{
  Html.TextBoxFor(v => v.Date);
}
else {
  //show whatever
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few similar questions like

- [Html.TextboxFor default value for Integer/Decimal to be Empty instead of 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887005/html-textboxfor-default-value-for-integer-decimal-to-be-empty-instead-of-0)
- [Display empty textbox using Html.TextBoxFor on a not-null property in an EF entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703860/display-empty-textbox-using-html-textboxfor-on-a-not-null-property-in-an-ef-enti/6186576)

If you have full control over the viewmodel, one option would be to make the date field nullable and have the accessor return `null` if the date is equal to `DateTime.MinValue`.

If you don't want to change your viewmodel, you can [write your own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052752/adding-your-own-htmlhelper-in-asp-net-mvc-3) html helper and put the logic to create an empty textbox there.  That allows you to keep logic out of your view, where it's difficult to test.

Answer (score 0):

Make your property nullable and it won't default to the min date.  If that's a database field and you can't do that then you should create a ViewModel property that is and have it compare against the min value and return null in the get{}